# Assign a React component to a variable with extra props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a component mapping function that loops through a list of objects which have a `type` key. The function returns an object of types of React components, it looks like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import cellBodyTypes from './cellBodyTypes';
import {
    GenericCellBody,
    SubData
} from './components/CellBody';

const columnMapper = {};

_.forEach(cellBodyTypes, (type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case cellBodyTypes.SUB_DATA:
            columnMapper[type] = SubData;
            break;
        case cellBodyTypes.DEFAULT:
            columnMapper[type] = GenericCellBody;
            break;
        default:
            columnMapper[type] = GenericCellBody;
    }
});

export default columnMapper;
```

And it's used like this:

```
renderCellBody = (columnType, cellData, index) => {
    const type = columnType || cellBodyTypes.DEFAULT;
    const CellBodyComponent = columnMapper[type];

    return <CellBodyComponent />;
}
```

And the render looks something like:

```
render (
    <div>
        {this.props.cellData.map((cell, index) => (
            <div key={cell.id}>
                {this.renderCellBody(cell.type, cell, index)}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

What I want to do is to be able to assign column types for new cases which utilize the same React components as other cases, but decorate those new column types with additional props. Something like:

```
case cellBodyTypes.NUMBER_SUB_DATA:
    columnMapper[type] = React.cloneElement(SubData, {someAdditionalProp: 'something'});
    break;
case cellBodyTypes.SINGLE_NUMBER:
    columnMapper[type] = React.cloneElement(GenericCellBody, {someAdditionalProp: 'something'});
    break;
```

I tried returning a clone of the React component using `React.cloneElement` but that does not work, as it gives me this error: `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Is there a way to do this? Am I close to the right path and just missing something? Thanks.

Comment: `this.props.cellData.map((cell, index) => ( <div key={cell.id}> ... ))`

Comment: @dfsq Thanks, that was a typo in the pseudo code I used, I know thats not the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because `React.cloneElement` return a react element, not component. So after

`columnMapper[type] = React.cloneElement(SubData,...`,

`columnMapper[type]` will containt an element.

But problem is that in `renderCellBody` function, you are trying to convert an element again into element by writing

```
return <CellBodyComponent />;
```

And that throws an error.

I would suggest that you keep `columnMapper` an array of `elements`. So the `switch/case` code should look something like this

```
_.forEach(cellBodyTypes, (type) => {
    switch (type) {
        case cellBodyTypes.SUB_DATA:
            // Store element instead of component
            columnMapper[type] = <SubData />;
            break;
        case cellBodyTypes.DEFAULT:
            // Store element instead of component
            columnMapper[type] = <GenericCellBody />;
            break;
        case cellBodyTypes.NUMBER_SUB_DATA:
            columnMapper[type] = React.cloneElement(SubData, {someAdditionalProp: 'something'});
            break;
        case cellBodyTypes.SINGLE_NUMBER:
            columnMapper[type] = React.cloneElement(GenericCellBody, {someAdditionalProp: 'something'});
            break;
        default:
            columnMapper[type] = <GenericCellBody />;
    }
});
```

So now `columnMapper` is an array of `elements`. Therefore in `renderCellBody` function, you don't need to convert them into `element` again. You can simply return the value

```
renderCellBody = (columnType, cellData, index) => {
    const type = columnType || cellBodyTypes.DEFAULT;
    const CellBodyComponent = columnMapper[type];

    // CellBodyComponent is already an element. So directly return it.
    return CellBodyComponent;
}
```

Comment: Ah, dang I totally forgot I could just return elements like you've pointed out. This helps me a achieve what I am trying to do, thanks!